# Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement): no such table: iris

Tags: r, sqldf

I am using R version 3.3.3 .I have installed sqldf package.but it is showing the below error when I am running the following query
sqldf("select * from iris")

Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: iris

Please help

Comment: try to do data(iris) before this ?

Comment: Either use a versiion of RSQLiter earlier than 2.0 or else use sqldf 0.4-11 just released.