# Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : duplicate column name: Ret

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf, rsqlite, fuzzyjoin

I have a bunch of sql queries that worked fine but now, for some reason, do not work any more. The data has not changed. The code has not changed.

I keep getting this error message:

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) :    duplicate column
>   name: Ret

These errors tend to happen with left joins. Find below an example:

```
 g.cper<-sqldf("select a.*, b.NAV_EUR, b.AUM_EUR
           from g2_c as a
            left join 
            nav_master as b
            on a.fund_id=b.fund_id and a.period = b.period")
```

None of the tables in question contain a variable named "Ret"

I recently updated all my packages.

This is legacy code. I tend to use dplyr::left_join when possible. But left_join will never do what a left join in SQL could achieve (inequalities as constraints, etc).

These are the packages I load:

> packages <- c("ISLR","gam","biglm","dplyr","gtools","tidyr",
>                 "randomForest","splines", "tree",  "pROC","lfe","lubridate",
>                 "stargazer",  "scales", "ggplot2", "scales", "data.table", "zoo","PerformanceAnalytics",
>                 "stats","proto", "timeSeries","timeDate","gsubfn","fBasics","DBI","RSQLite","sqldf",
>                 "RODBC", "tcltk","reshape","xts", "data.table","parallel",
>                 "lfe", "readr", "purrr", "tibble", "hms", "stringr", "lubridate", "forcats")

This is my sessioninfo ():

> sessionInfo() R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Red Hat Enterprise
>   Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo)
>
> locale:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792871/error-in-rsqlite-send-queryconnptr-statement-no-such-table-iris) LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8         [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
>   [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792871/error-in-rsqlite-send-queryconnptr-statement-no-such-table-iris) parallel  tcltk     splines   stats
>   graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792871/error-in-rsqlite-send-queryconnptr-statement-no-such-table-iris) forcats_0.2.0
>   stringr_1.2.0                 hms_0.3                        [4]
>   tibble_1.2                    purrr_0.2.2
>   readr_1.0.0                    [7] reshape_0.8.6
>   RODBC_1.3-14                  sqldf_0.4-10                  [10]
>   RSQLite_1.1-2                 fBasics_3011.87
>   gsubfn_0.6-6                  [13] timeSeries_3022.101.2
>   timeDate_3012.100             proto_1.0.0                   [16]
>   PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-14
>   [19] data.table_1.10.4             ggplot2_2.2.1
>   scales_0.4.1                  [22] stargazer_5.2
>   lubridate_1.6.0               lfe_2.5-1998                  [25]
>   Matrix_1.2-8                  pROC_1.9.1
>   tree_1.0-37                   [28] randomForest_4.6-12
>   tidyr_0.6.1                   gtools_3.5.0                  [31]
>   dplyr_0.5.0                   biglm_0.9-1                   DBI_0.5-1 
>   [34] gam_1.14                      foreach_1.4.3
>   ISLR_1.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792871/error-in-rsqlite-send-queryconnptr-statement-no-such-table-iris) reshape2_1.4.2
>   lattice_0.20-34  colorspace_1.3-2 chron_2.3-50     plyr_1.8.4
>   munsell_0.4.3     [7] gtable_0.2.0     codetools_0.2-15 memoise_1.0.0 
>   labeling_0.3     Rcpp_0.12.9      xtable_1.8-2     [13] digest_0.6.12 
>   stringi_1.1.2    grid_3.3.3       tools_3.3.3      sandwich_2.3-4
>   magrittr_1.5     [19] lazyeval_0.2.0   Formula_1.2-1    assertthat_0.1
>   iterators_1.0.8  R6_2.2.0

Not sure if this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792871/error-in-rsqlite-send-queryconnptr-statement-no-such-table-iris) Keep in mind I am using RSQLite_1.1-2 (earlier than 2.0)

I honestly do not know what's going on and have not found anything online...

**UPDATE I:** I have upgraded to sqldf_0.4-11 and RSQLite_2.0.... Still get this problem. I also tried loading sqldf (and dependencies).... Code still does not work

**UPDATE II:** First, I would like to thank **G. Grothendieck** for his help on this issue and for his R contributions all these years.

On this particular issue, I tried to run a test query using mtcars. This is the code:

`b<- sqldf("select a.*, b.mpg as test
          from mtcars as a
          left join 
          mtcars as b
          on a.mpg=b.mpg")`

**This query worked!!!**. I then run the code that was not working even after updating to sqldf 0.4.11 and RSQLite 2.0 (see Update I). To my surprise it now works!!!....**I do not know what happened**, but all my sqldf queries are now working. **FYI...I am working in AWS............ I sometimes get these unexplainable weird stuff happening....**

**UPDATE III** The problem is back. So I run the test code in update II again. This works. And after having run that test code, all my sqldf joins work again....GO FIGURE

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I was getting the same error message but it went away after upgrading `RSQLite` to 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In this reproducible example (using sqldf 0.4.11 and RSQLiute 2.0) it works as expected.

```
library(sqldf)

g2_c <- nav_master <- data.frame(fund_id = 1:2, period = 1:2, NAV_EUR = 0, AUM_EUR = 0)
sqldf("select a.*, b.NAV_EUR, b.AUM_EUR
       from g2_c as a
       left join nav_master as b
         on a.fund_id=b.fund_id and a.period = b.period")
```

giving:

```
  fund_id period NAV_EUR AUM_EUR NAV_EUR AUM_EUR
1       1      1       0       0       0       0
2       2      2       0       0       0       0
```